# JQuery and Phonegap resume event

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I would like to ask, how to run resume event in phonegap. I have JQuery code and I don't know, how to run this script during resume. What to write in addEventListener. Thanks for advices

```
    function onLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("resume", ***WHAT TO WRITE HERE?*** , false);
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#firsttext").text("Something");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29) function to the [resume](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume) event listener.

```
function onDeviceReady(){
      document.addEventListener("resume", callbackFunction , false);
    }

    function callbackFunction () {
     //This function will be called when the resume event is triggered
    }
```

In this case, when the `resume` event is triggered, `callbackFunction` will be called, This is where you would typically reload your saved variables etc.

Comment: I know how EventListener works, but I don't know how to run Jquery on resume? If jquery paste into function and call from resume event?

Comment: Jquery will be available when you resume the application.

Comment: Inside the callback function, you can use Jquery to reinitialize the view to what it was.